# How to download files using Android DownloadManager without knowing the filename?

Tags: android-download-manager, download-manager, content-disposition

I want to download the file from the URL such as -

mDownloadUrl = "https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=xxx";

The problem is that i do not know the filename and content type. It can be pdf, doc, mp3 etc. If i use

DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(mDownloadUrl));

setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(dir, filename)

This requires that i know the filename along with the file extension. Also all third party services like onedrive does not support HEAD call (Give 404 error), so i can not get file name from Content-Disposition header.

Is there a way to just specify URL and Directory path and download the file by original name as in content disposition header?

Comment: Does not support HEAD, or does not return Content-Disposition in the response? The former would be a severe bug that needs to be reported.

Comment: @JulianReschke I tried sending HEAD request to onedrive link using POSTMAN client. It did not respond. Do all servers support HEAD calls? I doubt that. At backend we can specify only allow POST or GET calls to a route. I think thats what onedrive has done.

Comment: Edit: by did not respond i mean it gave 404. i am updating question

Comment: So GET returns 200 and HEAD returns 404? Raise a bug report.